# Attempting to get this program to only print Usernames that are between 5 and 10 characters long

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have written a bash program that scans through /etc/passwd and prints out all of the usernames that are in the directory however i need the program to only print out usernames that are between 5 and 10 characters long.
I need to change it.

```
#!/bin/bash

MAXLENGTH=$(cut -d: -f1 < /etc/passwd | wc -L)
MINLENGTH=$MAXLENGTH
SMALLESTNAME=""

for NAME in $(cut -d: -f1 < /etc/passwd)
do
if [ ${#NAME} -eq $MAXLENGTH ]
then
        echo "The Longest UserName In The System 
Is:" $NAME
        echo " Its Length Is" $MAXLENGTH
elif [ ${#NAME} -lt $MINLENGTH ]
then
        MINLENGTH=${#NAME}
        SMALLESTNAME=$NAME
fi

done

 echo
 echo "The Smallest UserName In The System Is:" 
 $SMALLESTNAME
 echo "Its Length is:" $MINLENGTH
```

Comment: Please don't cross-post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53696947/1640661

Answer (score 3):

```
getent passwd | awk -F : 'length($1) >= 5 && length($1) <= 10 { print $1 }'
```

This will print the usernames that are between 5 and 10 characters long (inclusively).

For the shortest and longest names:

```
getent passwd |
awk -F : 's == "" || length($1) < length(s) { s = $1 }
          l == "" || length($1) > length(l) { l = $1 }
          END { printf("shortest: %s (%d chars)\n", s, length(s))
                printf("longest:  %s (%d chars)\n", l, length(l)) }'
```

Doing both things with a single pass over the password database (as a complete `bash` script, although `/bin/sh` should have been far more than enough since this script does not use anything `bash` specific, *any* shell would be able to run it):

```
#!/bin/bash
getent passwd |
awk -F : 'length($1) >= 5 && length($1) <= 10 { print $1 }
          s == "" || length($1) < length(s)   { s = $1   }
          l == "" || length($1) > length(l)   { l = $1   }
          END { printf("shortest: %s (%d chars)\n", s, length(s))
                printf("longest:  %s (%d chars)\n", l, length(l)) }'
```

Comment: would i put that in my already created program or on its own??

Comment: @IDontKnowWhatImDoing On its own.

Comment: yes well . tried that however it prints allot of extra things aswell i only need it to print out the username eg.
dvc18rkb:*:156726:513:Development Language Disorders Conf Off:/homedir/dvc18rkb:/bin/tcsh

where i just need the 'dvc18rkb"

Comment: @IDontKnowWhatImDoing Fixed now.

Comment: this now works, is there a way to implement it into my original code as i need to keep it all as a bash file and to print the smallest and largest name at the same time?

Comment: @IDontKnowWhatImDoing See update.

Answer (score 1):

Impractical but somewhat mesmerizing: bash [extended file patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
shopt -s extglob

getent passwd | 
  cut -d: -f1 | 
  while IFS= read -r name; do 
    [[ $name == ?????@(|?|??|???|????|?????) ]] && echo "$name"
  done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your homework solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
for NAME in $(cut -d: -f1 < /etc/passwd)
do
        if [[ ${#NAME} -gt 10 || ${#NAME} -lt 5 ]]
        then
                continue
        else
                echo "Username in the system is: $NAME"
                echo "Its length Is ${#NAME}"
        fi
done
```

You're welcome.

Comment: Would be worth full marks if you used a `while`-`read` loop reading from `getent passwd` instead.  Using a `for` loop over a command substitution is distinctly inelegant.  Also, it seems as if the user still wants to do the max/min calculation.  Also, what's with the `continue`? Can't you just test for the inverse logical condition and skip the empty `then`-`else` branch?

Comment: Thanks but its not homework

Comment: @IDontKnowWhatImDoing Show me some task that requires you to do this kind of operation on usernames that is _not_ homework...

Comment: @kusalananda it's pure unadulterated hacking of the original. Hence the inelegance.

Comment: @Dougie also this does not print put all of the user names that are between 5 and 10 charactersonly the longest and shortest i need to print out all usernames

Answer (score 0):

For a little more variety, `cut` and `grep`:

```
getent passwd | cut -d: -f1 | grep -Ex '.{5,10}'
```

This retrieves the passwd entries, cuts out the first field (username), then asks grep for an Extended regular expression match that spans the entire line (`-x`) where there are between 5 and 10 of any character (`.`).